# IS NOT NULL not "filtering" correctly in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working with Big Query and returning results as expected with one minor detail. Despite my `IS NOT NULL` restriction, I'm still getting a ton of `null` results. As best I can figure, it's checking to see if the wrong value is null.

What I want to check to see if it's `null` is the "firebase_screen" value. I've tried below:

```
SELECT
  event_name,
  event_timestamp,
  event_date,
  (
  SELECT
    value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST (event_params)
  WHERE
    key = "firebase_screen" and key IS NOT NULL) as app_screen,
FROM
  `my_table_name`
WHERE
  event_name = 'button_click'
```

And also tried:

```
SELECT
  event_name,
  event_timestamp,
  event_date,
  (
  SELECT
    value.string_value
  FROM
    UNNEST (event_params)
  WHERE
    key = "firebase_screen" and value.string_value IS NOT NULL) as app_screen,
FROM
  `my_table_name`
WHERE
  event_name = 'button_click'
```

Any ideas how I can properly "filter" out the `null` results?
In either case, I end up with the same results.

This is a SAMPLE of the raw JSON that I'm getting back from Big Query:

```
     {
        "key": "firebase_screen",
        "value": {
          "string_value": "home screen",
          "int_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "double_value": null
        }
      }
```

Here's a sample output that is the same for both queries.

```
| event_name   | event_timestampe | event_date | app_screen         |
|--------------|------------------|------------|-------------------|
| button_click | 1593616723965003 | 20200701   | null              |   
| button_click | 1593616726265005 | 20200701   | null              |   
| button_click | 1593616806351000 | 20200701   | maintain_screen_1 |
```

Comment: `key = "firebase_screen" and key IS NOT NULL` This is a tautology. If it equals that string, then it by definition is not null. And you didn't say you want to check the _key_ but the **value**. Surely you mean `string_value IS NOT NULL` or similar, to check the value is null, as you requested.

Comment: Typo...I copy and pasted the same thing @underscore_d. Fixing now.

Comment: Show the desired and current (wrong) outputs of the 2nd SQL query. You showed only one record, where the value is not null, but you complain that nulls are included. Where are they?

Comment: Just added a sample @underscore_d

Comment: Why does your output have a column named `trvscreen` but neither query does? Why does it have a value `maintain_screen_1` that's not in your input JSON?

Comment: That's just me copy and pasting poorly and trying to obfuscate some of the data. The JSON was meant to just be a sample. The `string_value` in the JSON is the value that is returned as null and that should be excluded if it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your app_screen field is a subquery in the select clause, if the result of that subquery is null, you will be selecting a null in the output.

Consider something like this:

```
select event_name, event_timestamp, event_date, value.string_value as app_screen
from `my_table_name`
left join unnest(event_params) ep
where event_name = 'button_click' -- main table logic
  and ep.key = 'firebase_screen' and ep.value.string_value is not null -- unnested logic
```

This should get you a lot closer, but without your exact table schema I can't guarantee this is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting back this error:

Field name string_value does not exist in STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>> at [28:47]

It's referring to the `value.string_value` in the last `AND` statement

Comment: I have made an edit.  Because you did not provide a schema, I had to guess a bit on where exactly `key` and `string_value` are located. If my edit does not work, the general flow of the query should work, you will just need to examine the prefixes and verify where the fields are actually located.

Comment: This got me on the right path and solved the issue! Thanks for your help.